# Ordenação pela posição do registro editado (sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quando eu insiro um novo registro, eu faço uma ordenação onde eu ordeno pelo último registro inserido.

```html
SELECT TOP(50) * FROM TB_CLIENTE_FORNECEDOR where status <> 'S' order by IDCLIENTEFORNECEDOR desc
```

Se eu estiver editando um registro de cujo id é 10, eu quero ordenar por este id.

Answer (score 0):

Especifique o valor do `ID` como parte de sua consulta, e utilize o operador *Menor ou Igual a* (`<=`):

```
SELECT TOP(50) * 
FROM   tb_cliente_fornecedor 
WHERE  status <> 'S' 
  AND  idclientefornecedor <= 10
ORDER  BY idclientefornecedor DESC
```

Referência:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174978.aspx